# Mail disappeared from Thunderbird while moving thousands of mails

Tags: email, thunderbird, amazon-web-services, imap

I recently changed hosting provider (small company to AWS) with my domain + e-mail. In the old situation, my sent mail was stored in a folder 'Sent Items'. In the new situation, my sent mail is stored in a folder 'Sent'.

I still have 10.000 sent messages in 'Sent Items' and wanted to move those to 'Sent', to have everything in the same folder.

Using Thunderbird, I tried to drag all mails from 'Sent Items' to 'Sent', but Thunderbird crashed. The problem: I've got 100 e-mails in Sent, 8.600 in 'Sent Items' and 1.300 in limbo.

When I login to Amazon WorkMail, my 'Sent Items' contains 9.900 mails and 'Sent' has 100.

- Where are those 1.300 e-mails in Thunderbird? (I checked all folders.)
- How do I get those 1.300 mails back in either 'Sent' or 'Sent Items'?
- How do I make sure Thunderbird doesn't become leading in the sense that it will also invisiblise the mails on the server?

I've tried to Refresh, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to repair the **Sent** or **Sent Items** folder?

Right click on **Sent** and/or **Sent Items** folder, then go to **Properties** and then click on **Repair folder**

Sometimes mail gets "lost" to Thunderbird on moving, and becomes visible again when you repair folder.

Comment: Yes, there they are! Thanks!

Any hints on how to safely move all those e-mails to the Sent folder?

Comment: try moving them in smaller chunks, and don't work on thunderbird while its moving, so it doesn't crash, problem is if it crashes on move, then you need to repair folder to reindex mail in folder

Comment: I would use something like imapsync to do it for you.

Comment: I did it with chunks of 500 - 1.000 mails and that worked well. Thanks again for the advise.